# PHP PDO fetch returns false

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I keep thinking on that "error" but can't say why it returns false.
I've already done a SELECT for this but that is in an other file..

```
 $result = $db->dbh->prepare("SELECT thumbs FROM skill WHERE id=? LIMIT 1");
 $result->bindParam(1, $id);
    // $id == 4 here
 $result->execute();
 $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    // $row == false > why ?
 $thumbs = $row['thumbs'];
```

When i'm trying to run this on PhpMyAdmin, it works well.

I execute this code on an AJAX call, and using the same config.php file for the $db conection.

Another question:

```
    $sql_in = $db->dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `voted_ip` (id, ip) VALUES (:id, :ip)");
    // $id == 4
    $sql_in->bindParam(":id", $id);
    $sql_in->bindParam(":ip", $ip, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sql_in->execute();
```

it inserts "0" and my ip. Why 0 ?

Please help

Comment: Check `$result->errorInfo()` for any errors.

Comment: It returns ["00000",null,null]. What does that mean?

Comment: That your query has run without errors. See http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php . If `fetch()` returns `false`, there are no (further) rows in the resultset. Are you sure there are rows returned with that very parameters?

Comment: `ipaddress` !== `person` you'd be better off using cookies

Comment: @Sirko Yes. Look here : http://puu.sh/bphSO/4834070ec4.png
My results are exhausted ? But it's my only select query on this page...

:andrew cookies are editable (same as the ip. but maybe ill doublecheck)

Comment: Do `var_dump($id)`. If it was a string value (which it would be if originated from $_GET or $_POST for example), and begins with a non-numeric character, it would be cast to integer zero by MySQL. In other words, does `$id` really contain _exactly_ the value you expect?

Comment: @Michael Berkowski thank you, this problem is solved :)

Comment: @Sw0ut What was the issue? What were the actual contents of `$id`? You should post (and later accept) your own answer below detailing what you found.

Comment: I cannot see the content because var_dump writes and doesn't goes into a variable.
This was a string and I used **$id = intval($id)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is becasue of the $id which is a STRING is converted at 0 by MySQL.

```
$id = intval($id);
```