# Populating form fields with query from 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have table `users` with fields `id`, `username`, `user_sex`, `user_city`. 
In columns `user_sex` and `user_city` I save int values `1 ... n`.

There are two more tables `user_sex` table with fields `user_id`,`male` and `female` and table `cities` fields `city_id` and `city_name`.

Now I want when user open his profile to be able to edit it but I can't populate fields. Fields are radio buttons for `sex` field and dropdown for the city.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6"> 
        <label class="radio-inline" for="radios-0">
            <input type="radio" name="user_sex" id="radios-0" value="1">
            Male
        </label> 
        <label class="radio-inline" for="radios-1">
            <input type="radio" name="user_sex" id="radios-1" value="2">
            Female
        </label> 
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="selectbasic">City</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
         <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control">
             <option value="">Choose your city</option>
         </select>
      </div>
</div>
```

I want this fields populated from user table.

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/612a8/2) of what I explained above.

Note: **For some reason this query doesn't return anything when I execute it in phpmyadmin**

Update:

```
$result = $pdo->prepare("
                        SELECT *, userSex.*, city.* 
                        FROM users usr
                        JOIN user_sex userSex ON usr.user_sex = userSex.user_id
                        JOIN cities city ON usr.user_city = city.city_id
                        WHERE id =?
                        LIMIT 1");


 $result -> bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
 $result -> execute();
 foreach ( $result as $row )                
 {
  echo '<legend><strong><i>'.$row['username'].'</i></strong></legend>
   <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-6"> 
        <label class="radio-inline" for="radios-0">
            <input type="radio" name="user_sex" id="radios-0" value="1">
            Male
        </label> 
        <label class="radio-inline" for="radios-1">
            <input type="radio" name="user_sex" id="radios-1" value="2">
            Female
        </label> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="selectbasic">City</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
         <select id="selectbasic" name="selectbasic" class="form-control">
             <option value="">Choose your city</option>
         </select>
      </div>
  </div>';
 }
```

So far is this. It is blank page. And as I said I don't know how exactly to populate the form.

If I make simple query like: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1` I've got `$row['username']` correctly. So i think the problem is in the query.

Comment: Could you show us the php part as well?

Comment: Yes, sorry .. i will update the question.

Comment: Question is updated.

Comment: I always use this check the radio for the user. `<?php if($row["user_sex"] == 1) { echo "checked"; } ?>` Put it inside the `<input type="radio">`.

Comment: On both radio buttons?

Comment: @JordanVit are you getting results from query I see you run this code `$result -> bindValue(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);` but you didn't initialize or declare `$id`?

Comment: @ARIFMAHMUDRANA it was the problem with the query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Query was not returning because you where joining usr.user_sex to user id. Find the working one below:

```
SELECT usr.*, userSex.*, city.*
   FROM users usr
JOIN user_sex userSex
    ON usr.id = userSex.user_id
JOIN cities city
    ON usr.user_city = city.city_id
WHERE id = 1
```

To check the radio buttons you can use the "checked" attribute. A simple check if the sex equals 1 or 2 should do.

So:

```
$sex = $row['user_sex'];
$maleChecked = ($sex == 1) ? "checked" : "";
$femaleChecked = ($sex == 2) ? "checked" : "";

<radio name="sex" value="1" $maleChecked >
<radio name="sex" value="2" $femaleChecked >
```

Comment: Thank's. This fixed the problem with the query. Can you show me how to load info now in the form?

Comment: I've got `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF)` when I put this in `foreach` loop.

Comment: Woops, made a boo boo

Comment: Thank's radios are working now. For the city dropdown do I need second query or how? I mean it will load user city but should also load other cities so user can choose another...

Comment: You need a second query that fetches all the cities for you and then do a similar check but put a "selected" attribute in the option field.

Answer (score 3):

your query returns boolean false see : [PHP PDO fetch returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25710494/php-pdo-fetch-returns-false)

so instead of

```
$result -> bindParam(1, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

please use below code :

```
 $id = 1;
 $result -> bindParam(intval($id), $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Than after you can play with your result like fetch data $result->fetch(); etc

Comment: I getting the ID .. i just didn't paste it in question. The problem was in the query.